# jQuery if element exists doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I got some Html like this.

```
<div class="box span4">
    <img src="demo/img/tile.png" />
</div>
<div class="box span4">
    Hello
</div>
```

Now if there's no image in my box I want to wrap the inner content. It works like a charm without the IF but I can't get it to work with the IF.

```
if($('.box').find('img').length < 1){
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="box_inner" />');
}
```

I have also tried:

```
if($('.box > img').length < 1){
    $(this).wrapInner('<div class="box_inner" />');
}
```

I thought it would be pretty simple and I've done something similar before, but nothing seems to work to get another div around the inner content of a box when there's no image inside.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try >= instead of < . But to be honest I think you need to add regex to identify the .img in your src.

Comment: Add this instead of 1 do == img[src*=\\/thread_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in your code refers to `window` object, you can use `not` method:

```
$('.box').not(':has(img)').wrapInner('<div class="box_inner" />');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NpRpk/

Comment: Thank you. This is the most simple and most effective way to do what I want. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Check for all div with class box.

```
$('.box').each(function(){
     if($(this).find('img').length == 0){
         $(this).wrapInner('<div class="box_inner" />');
     }    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it's right and good readable it's not the most effective way. Thank you for the answer!